# sed/grep to extract word between 2 characters

Tags: sed, grep

My sentence is

```
abcde^10=fgi^11=jkl^12=lmn
```

The sequence can be jumbled also
for eg.

```
abcde^11=jkl^12=lmn^10=fgi
```

The sequence can also be :

```
12=lmn^11=jkl^10=fgi^abcde
```

I want to print `lmn`.

I have gotten till thus far:

```
~$ echo abcde^10=fgi^11=jkl^12=lmn|grep -o '\^12=[^)]*\^' -> this doesnt print anything
```

```
~$ echo abcde^11=jkl^12=lmn^10=fgi|grep -o '\^12=[^)]*\^' -> this prints ^12=lmn^
```

Comment: Building on your grep and adding cut: `echo "abcde^11=jkl^12=lmn^10=fgi" | grep -o '\^12=[^)]*\^' | cut -d "=" -f 2 | cut -d "^" -f 1
lmn`

Comment: What is the expected output? `lmn` for both the given samples or just only for the first one or the second one? If you have `GNU grep`, does `grep -oP '\^12=\K[^)^]*'` solve your issue?

Comment: can you have `12=lmn^11=jkl^10=fgi^abcde` ?

Comment: Yes 12=lmn^11=jkl^10=fgi^abcde isalso possible

Comment: `sed 's/^\(.*\^\)\{0,1\}12=//;s/\^.*//'`

Comment: `grep -oP '(\^|^)12=\K[^)^]*'` works also if your sentence starts by `12=`

Comment: or `grep -oP '(?<![^^])12=\K[^)^]*'` (also, not sure why `)` is considered)

Comment: `Index=10; expr 'abcde^10=fgi^11=jkl^12=lmn' : ".*\^${Index}=\([^^]\+\)"` --> `fgi`

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a complete specification. If you simply want to print 3 characters starting from the 16th, please explain that (and try `s='abcde^11=jkl^12=lmn^10=fgi'; echo "${s:16:3}"`). If you want what is between the second `=` and the next `^`, please explain that (and try `s='abcde^11=jkl^12=lmn^10=fgi'; s="${s#*=}"; s="${s#*=}"; s="${s%%^*}"; echo "$s"`).

Comment: @jhnc - your solution works, can you help explain the parts ?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet - 12= can appear anywhere.

Comment: Delete the head, then delete any tail. Standard [BRE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03).

Comment: You should have include `112=foo` in your example so we could test for undesirably doing a partial match on the `12` part of `112`. Most of the answers you have so far would fail given input like `abcde^112=foo^12=lmn`. When posting any "pattern matching" question it's important to come up with sample input/output that really tests it, including regexp metachars and substrings.

Comment: safer version, if there could be no match: `sed -n 's/^\(.*\^\)\{0,1\}12=\([^^]*\).*/\2/p'`

Comment: If you split each record on `^` and each field on their first `=` then you got a parser for your input format

Comment: @Fravadona you also need to include `\n` in the RS or FS chars otherwise your final field would contain a trailing `\n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ echo 'abcde^10=fgi^11=jkl^12=lmn' | awk -v RS='[\n^]' -F'=' '$1==12{print $2}'
lmn

$ echo '12=lmn^11=jkl^10=fgi^abcde' | awk -v RS='[\n^]' -F'=' '$1==12{print $2}'
lmn
```

or using any awk:

```
$ echo 'abcde^10=fgi^11=jkl^12=lmn' | awk -v RS='^' -F'[=\n]' '$1==12{print $2}'
lmn
```

```
$ echo 'abcde^10=fgi^11=jkl^12=lmn' | awk -v RS='^' -F'[=\n]' '$1==12{print $2}'
lmn
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples in GNU `awk`, you can use `match` function of `awk` with regex `(^|\^)12=([^^]*)` in `while` loop.

```
awk '
{
  while(match($0,/(^|\^)12=([^^]*)/,arr)){
     print arr[2]
     $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the part between the first `12=` and the next `^` or the end of the string (not sure of that) you don't need external utilities. `bash` substitutions are enough:

```
s='abcde^10=fgi^11=jkl^12=lmn'
s="${s#*12=}"; echo "${s%%^*}"
```

Or:

```
[[ "abcde^10=fgi^11=jkl^12=lmn" =~ .*12=([^^]*).* ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

But if you prefer `sed`:

```
sed 's/.*12=\([^^]*\).*/\1/' <<< 'abcde^10=fgi^11=jkl^12=lmn'
```

Comment: these may fail if there is a three digit number ending "12"

Comment: There is not enough information in the question to decide what the regular expression should be. The title itself is totally misleading. And the OP apparently refuse to edit their question and add the missing parts.

Answer (score 0):

With grep using positive lookbehinds (prints only matches)

```
grep -Po '(?<=12=)[^^]+'
```

With sed (prints lines wihtout matches entirely)

```
sed -E 's/(^|.*\^)12=([^^]+).*/\2/'
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean like this ?

```
echo '
abcde^10=fgi^11=jkl^12=lmn 
abcde^11=jkl^12=lmn^10=fgi
12=lmn^11=jkl^10=fgi^abcde' |
```

---

```
nawk 'gsub(/.*12=|\^.+/,_)^_'
```

> 

```
gawk '$_=$2' FS='.*12=|\\^.+'
```

> 

```
mawk ++NF OFS= FS='.*12=|\^.+'
```

---

```
lmn 
lmn
lmn
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo 'abcde^10=fgi^11=jkl^12=lmn
abcde^11=jkl^12=lmn^10=fgi
12=lmn^11=jkl^10=fgi^abcde
' | awk -F'(^|\\^)12=' 'NF>1{sub(/\^.*/,"",$NF); print $NF}'
lmn
lmn
lmn
```

Comment: FWIW `-F'^12=|\\^12='` = `-F'(^|\\^)12='`, just to save the slight redundancy of specifying `12=` twice.